# How can I display escaped html on blog edit page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a CMS, and writing following code in my blog post to display code.

```
<pre>
  <code>
     &lt;input type=&quot;color&quot; name=&quot;favcolor&quot; /&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

It shows

```
<input type="color" name="favcolor" />
```

on my blog post page. However back on my edit page,once saved and refreshed, the code becomes like this:

```
<pre>
  <code>
    <input type="color" name="favcolor" />
  </code>
</pre>
```

How can I display the code as I wrote?
As far as I see, the code is saved as it is on mySQL databse. So I'm guessing I've done something wrong when fetching the contents..

Here is the function I used to display the content on my edit page.

```
function get_post($post_id){
    include('includes/database.php');

    $sql = 'SELECT post_id, post_content FROM blog_posts WHERE post_id = ?';

    try {
        $post_stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $post_stmt->bindValue(1,$post_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $post_stmt->execute();
        return $post_stmt->fetch();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error:'.$e->getMessage().'</ br>';        
        return array();
    }

}
```

On edit-post.php

```
$row = get_post($post_id);

<textarea name='post_content' id="post_content">
  <?php echo $row['post_content'];?>
</textarea>
```

To sum up, 
Problem: escaped HTML becomes unescaped when saved on edit page.
Question: How can I keep the escaped HTML on my edit page?

Comment: I didn't really understand what you mean but maybe the problem is because you are echoing the row in your edit-post.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so...

```
$row = get_post($post_id);

<textarea name='post_content' id="post_content">
  <?php echo htmlentities ( $row['post_content'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );?>
</textarea>
```